# Per-user SVN branch testing with Jenkins?

Tags: svn, jenkins, version-control, automated-tests

I'm about to start setting up a testing suite for an existing piece of software. The software repo is using SVN (I tried convincing them to move to git, but it's not going to happen in the near future), and each user has their own branches in `svnroot/branches/user/<branchname>`.

I would like to set up Jenkins to run a bunch of automated tests on the trunk, but I would also like to be able to run those tests on arbitrary branches *before* they are merged into trunk. Ideally, I would like those users to be able to login (via LDAP, I guess? They already have accounts on the system), and nominate a branch for running tests on.

I *don't* want to automatically run tests on all branches, because there are a lot of branches, many of which are inactive, and some of the tests will probably fairly resource hungry.

Is there a way to do something like this in Jenkins?

Comment: Why not have a job that points to each branch and does SCM polling so only runs when that branch has a change? That way you aren't listening on the whole repository in each job. I imagine you have a small finite set of user based branches. Alternatively, you could set up a parameterized job and have the user type in the name of the branch.

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky: read the third paragraph.

Comment: I did. My solution lets you choose which branches you are polling; so you aren't running against the whole repo. With polling, you don't run a build unless there are changes. So you wouldn't be running tests against inactive branches.